# c# Repository with Two Data Providers

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am creating one repository and I have to deal with two data providers(IFileDataAccess, IDbDataAccess) to build my model object(MyModel).

I have written below code, but I feel it's not correct, it's important to have MyModel class with all written properties as they all be used together.

Please suggest a good way to achieve this.

Thanks!

```
class MyModel
    {
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public Rates Rates { get; set; }
    public Balance Balance { get; set; }
    }

class MyRepository 
{
    private IFileDataAccess  _fileDataAccess;
    private IDbDataAccess  _dbDataAccess;

    public MyClass (IFileDataAccess fileDataAccess, IDbDataAccess dbDataAccess)
    {
        _fileDataAccess= fileDataAccess;
        _dbDataAccess=dbDataAccess;
    }

    public MyModel GetMyModel()
{
    return new MyModel(){Schedule=_dbDataAccess.GetSchedule(),Rates=_fileDataAccess.GetRates(), Balance=_fileDataAccess.GetBalance()};
}

}
```

Comment: You've got to provide more information.  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach. Your model is clean (as it should not reflect the data storage strategy) and your data access clear and seperated.

Comment: Is it a good approach to use two data providers in a repository? LIke I am doing IFileDataAccess & IDbDataAccess ?

Comment: sure, if you that's what your application needs.  The repository should hide  the 2 data providers from the application, but what the repository does internally can be reworked if you see a need

Comment: I dont understand why you even need a FileDataAccess. Further more i dont really get it, why your informations you want to obtain are stored in different places? Next thing is, a Repository should be designed as a singleton to avoid concurrent access

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're questioning your repository class because "it's doing too much"? Have a look at this change for example...

```
class MyModel
{
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public Rates Rates { get; set; }
    public Balance Balance { get; set; }
}

class MyFileDataRepository
{
    private IFileDataAccess _fileDataAccess;

    public MyFileDataRepository(IFileDataAccess fileDataAccess)
    {
        _fileDataAccess = fileDataAccess;
    }

    public Rates GetRates()
    {
        return _fileDataAccess.GetRates();
    }

    public Balance GetBalance()
    {
      return _fileDataAccess.GetBalance();
    }
}

class MyDbDataRepository
{
    private IDbDataAccess _dbDataAccess;

    public MyDbDataRepository(IDbDataAccess dbDataAccess)
    {
        _dbDataAccess = dbDataAccess;
    }

    public Schedule GetSchedule()
    {
        return _dbDataAccess.GetSchedule();
    }
}

class MyModelProvider
{
    private MyFileDataRepository _fileDataRepository;
    private MyDbDataRepository _dbDataRepository;

    public MyModelProvider(MyFileDataRepository fileDataRepository, MyDbDataRepository dbDataRepository)
    {
        _fileDataRepository = fileDataRepository;
        _dbDataRepository = dbDataRepository;
    }

    public MyModel GetModel()
    {
        return new MyModel
        {
            Schedule = _dbDataRepository.GetSchedule(),
            Rates = _fileDataRepository.GetRates(),
            Balance = _fileDataRepository.GetBalance()
        };
    }
  }
```